# Yii SQL CommandBuilder Get Random Results

Tags: sql, yii

I'm trying to query random results in my model.

```
public function ListingsRandom(){

    // This gets 10 random listings
    $results = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
    ->select('*')
    ->from('listings')
    ->random('RAND')
    ->limit(10)
    ->queryAll();                    



    return $results;
}
```

This does not work for me.

How can I get random 10 results from the table?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
    ->random('RAND')
```

To:

```
    ->order(array('RAND()'))
```

Comment: Thanks so much. ->order(array('RAND()')) this worked for me :)